# apache overflow RAM with redirect

Tags: php, apache, http-redirect

I have developed a website with php and apache on a dedicated centos7 vps. Recently Ram gets full and I cant even connect trough ssh to restart the server.
I've checked apache access log and around the issue there is following log:

> 151.244.81.99 - - [28/Aug/2016:16:11:22 ] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"

I've googled 302 and its redirect and I'm guessing there is problem is my code.
So I was wondering if its a flow in my code, how to find it or any idea would be welcome.
thanks in advance.